# WPF CheckBox Check not working after disabling and enabling in code behind

Tags: c#, wpf

I have ComboBox and enabling it based on a CheckBox. If I disable and enable checkbox in code behind then it stops working. However if I don't do that then the ComboBox gets enabled when the checkbox is checked and gets disable when the checkbox is unchecked.

Code Sample below:

```
<CheckBox x:Name="ckBox1" IsChecked="{Binding proceed, TargetNullValue=false}" Content="Proceed" FontSize="16"/>
```

ComboxBox:

```
<ComboBox x:Name="cmbOptions" SelectedValuePath="Content" SelectedValue="{Binding selOptions}" Width="89" IsEnabled="{Binding IsChecked, ElementName=ckBox1}" >
                                        <ComboBoxItem Content="Option 1"/>
                                        <ComboBoxItem Content="Option 2"/>
                                        <ComboBoxItem Content="Option 3"/>
                                        <ComboBoxItem Content="Other"/>
                                    </ComboBox>
```

Diabling:

```
var controls = this.sourceGrid.Children.OfType<Control>();
controls.ToList().ForEach(c => c.IsEnabled = false);
```

Enabling:

```
controls.ToList().ForEach(c => c.IsEnabled = true);
```

Comment: Have you tried `Mode=OneWay`?

Comment: Can you show us the code behind?

Comment: What are you changing in the code behind? The property "proceed" or the ckBox1.Enabled property?

Comment: @MikeEason, `Mode=OneWay` is not working.

Comment: @Shamshiel, am changing all the controls within the grid as you can see. I added the code behind.

Comment: The code behind you posted does what it's supposed to, but when you enable or disable the combobox in code behind it's breaking the binding on the IsEnabled for the combobox.  Either set the IsEnabled with the combobox or in codebehind, not both.

Comment: Thanks @StephenWilson, good to know but is there another way to achieve both?

Comment: See my answer below.

Answer (score 0):

Ok, this is not a pretty solution but it should let you do what you need to.  Basically you need to get a reference to the existing Binding object before setting IsEnabled to false.  Then after setting IsEnabled to false or back to true, reset the binding.  Full code below which I set in the Loaded event handler but just move to wherever you need it.

```
this.Loaded += (s, e) =>
    {
        var controls = this.sourceGrid.Children.OfType<Control>();
        controls.ToList().ForEach(c =>
        {
            ComboBox combo = c as ComboBox;
            Binding newBinding = null;
            if (combo != null)
            {
                newBinding = BindingOperations.GetBinding(combo, ComboBox.IsEnabledProperty);
            }

            c.IsEnabled = false;

            if (combo != null)
            {
                BindingOperations.SetBinding(combo, ComboBox.IsEnabledProperty, newBinding);
            }
        });

        controls.ToList().ForEach(c =>
        {
            ComboBox combo = c as ComboBox;
            Binding newBinding = null;
            if (combo != null)
            {
                newBinding = BindingOperations.GetBinding(combo, ComboBox.IsEnabledProperty);
            }

            c.IsEnabled = true;

            if (combo != null)
            {
                BindingOperations.SetBinding(combo, ComboBox.IsEnabledProperty, newBinding);
            }
        });
    };
```

I must stress that this code isn't pretty so please refactor out properly as per your own implementation.

Answer (score 0):

You don't need any code-behind to disable and enable your controls. Do it in XAML.

```
<Checkbox x:Name="enablingCheckBox" Content="Enabled?" IsChecked="{Binding IsEnabled}"/>
<Grid IsEnabled="{Binding IsEnabled, Mode=OneWay, ElementName=enablingCheckBox}">
    <Button Content="Sample"/>
    <ComboBox/>
</Grid>
```

Setting the `IsEnabled` property in a grid to `false` automatically disables all the controls that belong to that grid.

Comment: The problem is I don't need to disable the entire grid but only certain controls.

Comment: Then set the binding on those controls' `IsEnabled` property.